# Angular2: Can you explain this *ngFor command followed by a function?

Tags: angular

The great article posted yesterday by Kara Erickson @ http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html
demos:

```
<p *ngFor="#item of items; trackBy:myTrackBy; #i=index"> 
   {{i}}: {{item}}
</p>
```

and I am wondering what is

`trackBy:myTrackBy?`

it's a custom function that gets a param passed?
I would have asked on the blog but can't post replies, thus posting here

and code sample of trackBy:myTrackBy would look be GREATLY appreciated

TX

Sean

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363987/angular2-ngfor-inside-tree-model-wrong-order-when-remove-and-then-add-elements

Comment: any official docs on this trackBy?

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation.

Comment: found the best docs: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3020-understanding-object-identity-with-ngfor-loops-in-angular-2-beta-3.htm