# Angular2, RC5: Not adding duplicate values in dropdown

Tags: angular

I am getting tests values from remote server, GroupID values can be duplicated, but I wish my dropdown will show values without duplication,
I tried the following code, which is not working

```html
<th>
<select class="form-control" (change)="reloadPosts({ GroupID: u.value })" #u>
<option value="">Select group id...</option>
<template *ngFor="let test of tests"> <option *ngIf="!test" value="{{ test.GroupID }}">
{{ test.GroupID }}
</option></template>
</select>
</th>
```

how can I do it with angular rc5 and above

thanks

Comment: Did it work with RC.4? What values are you using (string, object, ...)?

Comment: only rc5. - values are strings

Comment: Try with objects instead or `trackBy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363987/angular2-ngfor-inside-tree-model-wrong-order-when-remove-and-then-add-elements/35195155#35195155

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a simple pipe...

```
@Pipe({ name: 'unique', pure: false })

export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return _.uniq(value);
    }
}
```

Then in your html use `*ngFor="let test of tests | unique"`

The pipe example uses [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) but feel free to write the filter any way you'd like.

More information on [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve this using pipe, so I modified my component code,
see:
[Angular2, create new array/map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352000/angular2-create-new-array-map/39356235#39356235)