# Angular2, create new array/map

Tags: angular

I have json array - "tests"
inside one of the keys is "GroupID"
I wish to take all the "GroupID" and create new array that will include it
(if possible as map - so no duplicated)
I tried the following, but groupID contains only 1 value
I tried .push, [], and many other ways and always getting errors
how can I do it?

```js
...
 groupID: any[];
...
 for (var index = 0; index < this.tests.length; index++) {
     var element = this.tests[index];
     this.groupID = element.GroupID;
    }

      console.log(this.groupID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array, replace

```
groupID: any[];
```

With

```
groupID: any[] = [];
```

Then, also replace

```
this.groupID = element.GroupID;
```

With

```
this.groupID.push(element.GroupID);
```

Comment: Is there a way to add only if element.GroupID does not already exist in array?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] thanks also to beetleJuice

added only if not existing in array:

```js
...
 groupID: any[] = [];
...
    for (var index = 0; index < this.tests.length; index++) {
         var element = this.tests[index];
         if (this.groupID.indexOf(element.GroupID) == -1 ){
          this.groupID.push(element.GroupID);
         }
     }
```