# *ngFor Behaviour on primitive data type

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a list of objects which I am displaying using a `*ngFor` on the HTML page. Now the user interacts with UI and changes one of the primitive values(boolean, from false to true).

As per my understanding the `*ngFor` will only render the changes if the list object is modified completely i.e. removed and added again to the list. If I am right on this concept, then can you  please suggest a method to reflect the change in the primitive type without re-initializing the component or modifying the object reference.

**For Example:**

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of list">
        <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.selected"></md-checkbox>
  </div>
```

User clicks on the checkbox, but the checkbox has to be ticked after certain validations from server. So let's say the checkbox needs to be unchecked and user gets a message on snack bar. So I loop through the list and modify `item.selected` to false. But, the change is not reflected as i modified the primitive type selected(boolean) in the object item. So how to render the new value without reloading or initializing the page again.

Please let me know if more input is required.

Comment: you can create pipe for this, it will helps you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive please?

Comment: you can create a pipe that will check you boolean flag, see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use primitive values, you need `trackBy`

```ts
  <div *ngFor="let item of list trackBy:trackByIdx">
        <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.selected"></md-checkbox>
  </div>
```

```ts
  trackByIdx(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

See also [Angular2 NgFor inside tree model: wrong order when remove and then add elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363987/angular2-ngfor-inside-tree-model-wrong-order-when-remove-and-then-add-elements/35195155#35195155)

**update according to the discussion below**

Changing a boolean value bound by `ngModel` when the input value is changed, may cause `ngModel` not being updated. Adding an artificial change and callign `detectChanges` can be used to work around.

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

deactivate(index: number) {
  this.list[index][0] = true;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.list[index][0] = false;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  console.log(this.list);
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HTH0MqTTXe4BAEmMuahc?p=preview)

Comment: Oh my... are you kidding me! I've had several cases already where i thought that this could not be fixed. But apparently, angular already thought about this. Thanks gunter :D. Ah yes, it seems to be relatively new. Still great

Comment: these indexes are stored by angular, can we reset this list of indexes from the component?

Comment: No. What's the purpose?

Comment: I have a pagination feature, where user is moving to next page(data fetched using ajax call, instead of changing the url). The current changes made on first page are also reflected on the data of second page on the very same indexes.

Comment: Seems like you're using the indexes for something else than what is shown in my answer.

Comment: As per my understanding, trackBy is being used to segregate the data based on index. But what i wanna achieve is that, reflect the primitive value from the model on the UI, after I have toggled it in the component.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what " reflect the primitive value from the model on the UI, after I have toggled it in the component." means.

Comment: `trackBy:trackByIdx()` should be `trackBy:trackByIdx` without `()`. What's the problem with the Plunker?

Comment: When i click the checkbox, I have called a change event where i set the checked flag to false. But then also the checkbox is getting checked instead of remaining as unchecked.

Comment: This is `ngModel` not recognizing that the value changed from `false` to `true` to `false` https://plnkr.co/edit/hmwkhcNPDgUDW3iiCYln?p=info shows a workaround.

Comment: what is the change? Seems like the same plunk which i had created!

Comment: Sorry. Plunker doesn't seem to work currently. This one https://plnkr.co/edit/hmwkhcNPDgUDW3iiCYln?p=preview should contain the changes but I couldn't run and test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, it worked. If you can post this answer as well in the response that would be really fruitful for others too i guess!

Comment: Glad to hear this worked for you. I updated my answer.