# How properly bind an array with ngModel in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngmodel

Let's suppose I have an array [1,2,3]. I want to iterate all items and bind each to ngModel. When I run this code after changing the first element, the second one is getting the same value. What's the problem?

```
<div *ngFor="let x of array; let i = index;">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="x[i]">
</div>
```

Comment: Just do `[(ngModel)]="x"` should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863074/ngfor-behaviour-on-primitive-data-type/40863118#40863118

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ngFor` by default uses object identity to compare values, this breaks when primitive values (number, string, boolean) are used, because they change identity when modified). Using `trackBy` allows to configure ngFor to zse the index instead of identity:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of array; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIdx">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="array[i]">
</div>
```

```
trackByIdx(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: wow fantastic this took me ages. I had an input field, in a component, that lost focus on every key press. This fixed it. Simple array of strings as you state works fine if using array of objects and referencing keys in object.

Comment: This fixed it for me too! thanks!