# Angular two-way binding for select with object

Tags: angular, select, checkbox, binding, two-way

Actually, i'm trying to bind the array of object to select input. I'm trying in this way, [(ngModel)]="users[i].roles", where 'users' is outer array and 'roles' is another array inside users. Here, roles is array of key value pairs like,

```
roles = [{'code': 1, 'desc: ''},{'code': 2, 'desc: ''},{'code': 3, 'desc: ''}]
```

How can i bind the 'code' from this array.

My HTML code,

```
 <mat-select placeholder="User Roles" [(ngModel)]="users[i].roles" matTooltip="{{users[i].roles}}" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let role of userRoles" [value]="role.code">{{role.desc}}</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

Comment: Do you have *ngFor to loop through users? Could you provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. I solved this problem by modifying code in this way...

```
for (let user of this.users) {
   user.userRoles = [];
   for(let role of user.roles)
   {
     user.userRoles.push(role.code);
   }
}
```

In html,

```
<mat-select placeholder="User Roles" [(ngModel)]="users[i].userRoles" matTooltip="{{users[i].userRoles}}" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let role of userRoles" [value]="role.code">{{role.desc}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use `*ngFor` inside a `<div>` element

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="role.code">
</div>
```

for more details look here.. 
[How properly bind an array with ngModel in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991497/how-properly-bind-an-array-with-ngmodel-in-angular)

Comment: You have no need use index in template. [(ngModel)]="role.code"

Answer (score 0):

put it in an ngFor :

in .ts :

```
roles= [{'code': 1, 'desc: ''},{'code': 2, 'desc: ''},{'code': 3, 'desc: ''}]
```

in .html

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles;let index=index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="roles[index].code">
</div>
```