# Why changing an select change others when using ngFor and ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to let the user create a couple of selects, choose the options and agreggate these options in an array to be sent to a parent component.

I'm trying to do this with an `*ngFor` that loops an array of strings (`valueInputs`), creating a select for each element. An add button push a new empty string to `valueInputs`, thus increasing the amount of selects. Finally, each select updates an index of `valueInputs` via `ngModel`.

Here's a Stackblitz to show it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q5nwjq

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  valueInputs = ['', '', ''];
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let valueInput of valueInputs; let i = index">
  <select
    [(ngModel)]="valueInputs[i]">
    <option value="" disabled>Select an option...</option>
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</ng-container>

<div>
  <button (click)="valueInputs.push('')">Add input</button>
  <p>Value Inputs: {{ valueInputs | json }}</p>
</div>
```

Problem is: when I choose an option for the first select, the second select changes too! The actual value in the second `valueInputs` index doesn't change, only the selected option.

This happens to all selects. You change one, the next changes too.

Does this make any sense? Or it's a bug in Angular? Do you have any suggestions to achieve the same results?

Comment: You are using the same model for every input, this is cause of error. I think, that you should try FormArray instead. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8zzqj?file=src/app/app.component.html). To use ngFor with primitive data types you have to use "trackBy"

Two modifications:

```
  trackByIdx(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

and in your html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let valueInput of valueInputs; let i = index; trackBy:trackByIdx">
```

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46991565/2050306) for more details.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!