# Angular - trackBy with array of primitives

Tags: angular

I've read a documentation, I've tried to google it and check with code but still I can't find an answer.

I have an array of string, for example
`['Tom', 'Sarah', 'Ben']`. Its content will change dynamically and regularly. I'd like to use a trackBy function with it.

1. Generally, is there sense to do it?
2. If so, how should I use trackBy with such array? I want to avoid converting data to `object` with id.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Roghul, I suggest you [use `trackBy` with primitive arrays to avoid sorting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863074/ngfor-behaviour-on-primitive-data-type/40863118#40863118).

Answer (score 1):

A typical way is to use index.

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let e of array; trackBy: trackByFunc;">
   ...
</div>
```

**ts**

```
trackByFunc = (index: number, value: string) => index;
```